# In GitHub Actions, how can I trigger on push but only if a PR is active?

Tags: github, github-actions

Say I have 2 branches, a feature branch and a develop branch.

There's no SLA on feature branch normally, meaning I can push broken code up to it all day long and no CI build should be triggered.

Then I open a PR into develop.  I trigger a CI build action on pull_request: created.  Let's say this build fails.  By default I can't merge the PR, which is correct.

Now I want to push edits to feature branch to update the PR.  I want *these* pushes to trigger a CI build (because we're now working inside an open PR).  I don't want to allow the PR to proceed/be merged until these push-CIs pass.

How can I do that in GitHub Actions?   I tried `on pull_request: edited` but that didn't work for me.

I'm looking for the functional equivalent of:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    if: inside_open_pr
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the event `pull_request` and don't specify activities or specify the activity `synchronize`:

```
on:
  pull_request:
```

> Note: By default, a workflow only runs when a `pull_request`'s activity type is `opened`, `synchronize`, or `reopened`. To trigger workflows for more activity types, use the types keyword.

[source](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)

> if you push a new commit to the HEAD ref of a pull request then this “synchronize” event will be triggered. This is because the system is syncing the pull requests with the latest changes. This will NOT trigger if the base ref is updated.

[source](https://github.community/t/what-is-a-pull-request-synchronize-event/14784)

If you also need to react to a change of the base branch, then you have to add the activity `edited`.

[source](https://github.com/google/go-github/issues/1617)

Answer (score 2):

If `pull_request` is not an option, you can try using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-current-pull-request